# Android Dual Sim Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, dual-sim

How can I emulate an Android device with Dual sim support? It's important that the Android level is 5.1 or higher. This emulator is intended to send/receive SMS

Comment: Take a look at this project, 

https://github.com/seek-for-android

Sample project

https://github.com/seek-for-android/hello-smartcard-app

Wiki

https://github.com/seek-for-android/pool/wiki

Comment: @Antonio: I do not think that the Android SDK emulator offers support for this. You might take a look at Genymotion or other non-Google emulators, to see if they have options for this. On the whole, though, the closer you get to real hardware (e.g., SIMs), the worse emulators do at emulating reality.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @CommonsWare. Yes, I've checked Genymotion and try to find other emulators with no luck. Maybe someone has found a way to emulate dual sim devices, that's why I started this bounty

Comment: @kareemadel, but the device should be flashed to use this library, should not it?

Comment: @Antonio you need to patch the Android emulator https://github.com/seek-for-android/pool/wiki/EmulatorExtension

Comment: from my experience each dual-sim android device is implemented and behaves differently then other dual-sim devices, even devices from the same manufacturer, like Samsung, may display different behavior. For example the call-log db column used for differentiating between sms on sim 1 or 2 have many possible options depending on the device

Answer (score 1):

May this is help you:

Buddy in Document it is said that Emulators are supported with simulated SimCard..
**"A GSM modem, including a simulated SIM Card"** [More Information](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

And There are some patches available which allows sim card support in emulator using standard USB PCSC reader...

Here are some links which may guide you through..

- http://simhacks.github.io/android-emulator/
- http://blog.codepainters.com/2010/11/20/android-emulator-patch-for-configurable-imei-imsi-and-sim-card-serial-number/

thank you...