# How to configure a virtual Genymotion or AVD capable of supporting dual sim card?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion, dual-sim

I need to test an application that requires dual sims, that is, two sim cards. However, the default AVD that comes with Android Studio is not capable, as far as I know, of supporting this type of device.
Does anyone have any idea on how to go about that?

Comment: This is a useful question, but possibly too broad or off-topic. Please mention what you have tried, which documentations/forums/etc you read, and what evidence your conclusion is based on (besides "_I_ couldn't find this option"). Related question (no answer so far): http://stackoverflow.com/q/34450121/3372061

Comment: I've tried many configurations on the default AVD but none of them allows me to have two sims cards installed on the virtual device. As far as the Android version, the application that I am debugging only works for android 5.1 or greater.